# How can I have the iterative results from two sed commands printed on the same line of an output file?

Tags: sed

I have more than 4,000 text files that contain data from a fitting - different physical values derived from applying a simple model. The files have the naming convention: file_##,##_hill5.txt (where ##,## is a coordinate representation for each file). I need one particular data value as well as a portion of the filename to be printed to the same output file. Looking around the available answers to sed questions and editing for my needs, I came up with:

```
ls *.txt | sed -n '/^# Tau:  */s///p;y/ /\n/' > results.txt
```

-- this command derives the value of tau, i.e. ????? from "Tau: ?????" from each text file.

The second sed command that I have:

```
sed -n s/.*_\([0-9]*,[0-9]*\)_.*/\1/p * > results.txt
```

derives the ##,## coordinate values from the filename.

The output from running each sed code on the set of files is:

```
3.09428
3.35559
3.75969
4.42674
5.57755
```

and

```
24,15
23,14
21,17
17,18
19,10
```

However, I would like the tau-value and sets of digits to be printed side-by-side; namely,

```
3.09428  24,15
3.35559  23,14
3.75969  21,17
4.42674  17,18
5.57755  19,10
```

Is this possible using a single sed command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I have the iterative results from two sed commands printed on the same line of an output file?

Use `paste` or other tools.

> Is this possible with sed?

Not solely in `sed`, no. External tools or extra preformated arguments are  needed.